# Deleting/replacing data inside text file

Tags: php

I want to do if conditional between text data and variable data then delete the line

#### Example

I have a txt data with usernames like ( one two one three one) every user in line,
And i want to delete all data except "one" username

#### My Code;

```
if(file_get_contents('visitors.txt') != "one") {
    
    $GetLine = ;
    
    function removeLine ($url, $lineToRemove) 
    { 
        $data = file_get_contents($url); 
        $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data); 
        $lineNo = 1; 
        foreach($lines as $line) 
        { 
            $linesArray[$lineNo] = $line; 
            $lineNo++; 
        } 
        unset($linesArray[$lineToRemove]); 
        return implode("\n", $linesArray); 
    } 

    $data = removeLine ("username.txt", $getLine); 

    echo $data 
}
```

the function is used to remove lines.

My problem is doing if with the `data + $getLine` number, I just want to remove all the lines except line that has one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can simply do it with a regular expression:

```
$file = preg_grep('#one#', file('file.txt'));
```

This will make `$file` an array holding only lines containing the string "one". To turn the array back into a string, you just `implode` it.

If you only want to echo the lines containing "one", you can also use [iterators](http://blog.gordon-oheim.biz/2011-05-16-Iterating-File-Contents-With-SPL/):

```
$file = new RegexIterator(new SplFileObject("file.txt"), '#one#');
foreach ($file as $content) {
    echo $content, PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will go over the file line by line and echo any line having the string one in it. The benefit is that it doesn't use two arrays as intermediate structures.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, you shouldn't be defining functions inside an if statement.

Also, unless I'm misunderstanding, you shouldn't even need line numbers.

```
function remove_line( $data, $remove ){
    $lines     = explode( PHP_EOL, $data ); // Convert to Array
    $new_lines = ''; // Start a new variable we'll add to in a loop

    foreach( $lines as $line ){
        $line = trim( $line ); // Trim Whitespace

        if( $line != $remove ){
            // Line isn't a line we want removed, so save it plus an EOL
            $new_lines .= $line.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    return $new_lines;
}
```

Now if you load in a file like so: `$file = file_get_contents( 'my-file.txt' );` that contains the following:

```
One
Two
One
Three
One
```

Once you run it through the `remove_line` function, you'll end up something like:

```
$file     = file_get_contents( 'my-file.txt' );
$new_file = remove_line( $file, 'One' );

var_dump( $new_file ); // Returns: string(10) "Two Three "
```